# How to automatically insert several tkinter items in Tk() window using classes

Tags: python, tkinter

I apologize in advance if this is a stupid simple question, but i am really bad att python classes and can't seem to get it to work!

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

a = Tk()

class toolsGUI():

    def __init__(self, rootWin):
        pass

    def frame(self):
        frame = Frame(rootWin)
        frame.configure(bg = 'red')
        frame.grid()


    def button(self, binding, text):
        btn = Button(rootWin, text=text)
        btn.configure(bg = 'orange', fg = 'black')
        btn.bind('<'+binding+'>')
        btn.grid(row=1, sticky = N+S+E)
```

I simply want the `button()` or `frame()` to understand that `rootWin` is the same as in `__init__`, in this case `rootWin` should be variable `a`, thus placing the button in the Tk() window. After looking around, I understand that this is not the way to do it. Do anyone have another suggestion that might work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close. You are passing `a` to the `toolsGUI` initializer which is the right first step. You simply need to save this as an instance variable, then use the variable whenever you need to reference the root window:

```
def __init__(self, rootWin):
    ...
    self.rootWin = rootWin
    ...

def frame(self):
    frame = Frame(self.rootWin)
    ...
```

An alternative is to have `toolsGUI` inherit from Frame, in which case you can put all of the widgets in the frame instead of the root window. You then need the extra step of putting this frame inside the root window.

```
class toolsGUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, rootWin):
        Frame.__init__(self, rootWin)

    def frame(self):
        frame = Frame(self)
        ...
a = Tk()
t = toolsGUI(a)
t.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
a.mainloop()
```

As a final bit of advice: don't user variables that are the same name as methods if you can avoid it. "frame" is a poor choice of function names. Instead, call it "create_frame" or something, otherwise it could be confused with class `Frame` and the local variable `frame`